# Developing a pie-chart using Jfree to add it as a plugin in JIRA

Tags: jira, pie-chart, jira-plugin

I have to develop a pie-chart using some coding and must make that file available as a plugin(jar) to be displayed in JIRA.. Can any one help me with the coding part of displaying pie-chart ?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. CustomWare (http://www.customware.net) and many of the other Atlassian Experts can assist with creating custom plugins for JIRA. There's also my O'Reilly book "Practical JIRA Plugins" and the tutorial at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Creating+a+JIRA+Report

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your link has given me a good idea.. Can u guide me to a link where it can display pie-chart?